# How can I require thread-safety of parameters in an interface?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Suppose I have some interface that takes some set of numbers `foo` and performs some permutation `bar` on them:

```
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual std::vector<double> PerformBar(const std::vector<double>& foo) = 0;
  virtual void SetBar(std::function<double(double)>&& func) = 0;
};
```

If the implementation were single-threaded, there would be no issue, but what if my implementation attempts to parallelise its task?

```
class Impl final : public Interface
{
public:
  std::vector<double> PerformBar(const std::vector<double>& foo) override
  {
    std::vector<double> result(foo.size());
    std::thread t1([&]()
      {
        for (int i = 0; i != foo.size() / 2; ++i)
          result[i] = bar(foo[i]);
      });

    std::thread t2([&]()
      {
        for (int i = foo.size() / 2; i != foo.size(); ++i)
          result[i] = bar(foo[i]);
      });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return result;
  }

  void SetBar(std::function<double(double)>&& func) override
  {
    bar = func;
  }

private:
  std::function<double(double)> bar;
};
```

Currently, my interface does not make it clear to the user that `func` should be thread-safe, nor does it enforce that the implementation assume it is *not* thread safe.

Other than adding comments, how can I modify my interface to ensure that the user understand that `func` must be thread-safe?

Comment: There is no such option afaik. I'd place a proper comment near function declaration.

Comment: By renaming to `PerformParallellBar` ?

Comment: This sounds like it should be handled by the documentation.  One hacky way you could do it is make the function a template anf then name the function `SomeThreadSafeFunctionThatTakesAndReturnsDouble`

Comment: [OT]: the rvalue reference on std::function is strange BTW.

Comment: Even more than thread safety, the function should probably be *pure*, I mean same input give same output. (or maybe you accept a thread safe function `random`)...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (aside from the obvious documentation) btw - this is a sketch, not compiling code..

```
template <typename MutexType>
class Interface {
public:
  std::vector<double> PerformBar(const std::vector<double>& foo) {
    // Lock the mutex
    return DoPerformBar(foo);
  }

  void SetBar(std::function<double(double)>&& func) {
    // Lock the mutex
    return DoSetBar(forward(func));
  }

protected:
  virtual std::vector<double> DoPerformBar(const std::vector<double>& foo) = 0;
  virtual void DoSetBar(std::function<double(double)>&& func) = 0;

private:
  MutexType mutex_;
};

class SingleThreadedImpl final : public Interface<boost::interprocess::null_mutex>
{
protected:
  // Do the protected methods
};

class ParallelImpl final : public Interface<std::mutex>
{
protected:
  // Do the protected methods
};
```